# How to disable ASP-style PHP tags within a specific file?

Tags: php, underscore.js

I have an issue with a PHP file that embeds some Javascript in the page.  The JS is using the underscore templating engine, which happens to use ASP-style tags (`<% ... %>`) for output.

The client's PHP configuration has the ASP-style tags enabled, which is breaking the file syntax.

Is there any kind of directive I can add at the top of the file, or any other trick to get the PHP processor to ignore these tags?  I'm specifically looking for a way to do this **without modifying php.ini**.  But if that's the only way, please let me know.

Comment: How is your question related to underscore.js?

Comment: because it's possible that someone who uses underscore.js has experienced the same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this `.htaccess` file:

```
php_flag asp_tags off
```

And if you just want to disable the asp tags for just one file uses this rule here:

```
<files file-with-asp-syntax.php>
php_flag asp_tags off
</files>
```

Comment: what if I wanted to apply the setting to an entire directory?

Comment: If you just remove the file directive/tags the asp styled Tags are activated for the hole directory.

Comment: Awesome.  Technically i asked how to *disable* them... would you mind updating? It wouldn't let me submit an edit for < 6 characters

Answer (score 1):

Is the client's PHP configuration running on a windows server? If so you should be able to set PHP config on a per-directory basis by adding an .ini file in to that application's directory.

It used to be possible to change the use of tags via `init_set()` at run time for example `ini_set('asp_tags', 0)`, but I'm not sure if the latest versions of PHP still allow this.

On an Apache server you might be able to change the setting by adding `php_flag asp_tags Off` to your .htaccess file

I can't test any of this right now, but hopefully this will give you somewhere to start.

Comment: thanks for the ini_set tip.  According to [these docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php), it's not available with the asp_tags setting, but it pointed me in a useful direction.

Answer (score 1):

### I found a way to do it that works GREAT for underscore tags:

**page.php:**

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    var template = '<?php echo <<<HEREDOC

        <h1>\
            <%- model.title %>\
        </h1>\
        <% if (model.body) { %>\
            <p>\
                <%- model.body %>\
            </p>\
        <% } %>\

HEREDOC;
    ?>';
</script>
...
```

### Notes

The blank lines at the beginning and end of the HEREDOC serve two purposes:

- Prevents you from accidentally escaping the closing quote (`'`) in the javascript
- Makes it so the indentation and linebreaks are exactly how they would be without the added `HEREDOC` wrapper.

### Caveats

This is a poor choice for escaping ASP tags surrounding actual PHP, because the `HEREDOC` tag is interpolated the same way as a double-quote (`"`) string in PHP, where variables are output into the resulting file. Docs: [PHP String - Variable Parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

If you have control over your server environment and can rely on PHP > 5.3, then you can use NOWDOC to avoid this caveat altogether. The NOWDOC is distinguished from a HEREDOC by the single-quotes around the identifier, and prevents interpolation of PHP variables within the enclosed text. Docs: [PHP String - Nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)